# How to use query1 || query2 in .find() mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How can i use two querys instead of one? If the first query1 isnt valid, i want the .find() function to use query2, something like `.find({query1} || {query2})` Here is the contest where i want to use it:

```
db.collection("cars").find({user1: from, user2: to}).toArray(function (err, result){
      if(err) {
          reject(err);
      } else {
          resolve(result);         
      }
});
```

Comment: see [$or query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $or, here is a sample:

```
db.collection("cars").find({$or: [ {query1}, {query2} ]}).toArray(function (err, result){
      if(err) {
          reject(err);
      } else {
          resolve(result);         
      }
});
```